# Handling salt stains on a wood floor

Tags: capoeira

With the current pandemic, my Capoeira classes have moved to online. I was practicing outdoors, but the dropping temperatures and earlier sunset has put the kibosh on that. The only room in the house that currently has sufficient floor space and not too many things that might get kicked over is a guest room upstairs with a wood floor (I don't know enough about flooring to describe it properly, but it's slats of wood that have been nailed down, I think. At the least, they don't seem to shift underfoot as have some wooden floors I've encountered that are more loosely fastened). My problem is that I sweat a lot, and while I've been wiping the floor down with towels during class, and going over it weekly with a wet towel followed by a dry one, part of the room is starting to developing white stains from the salt in my perspiration (or at least I assume that's the source. They're roughly circular, like salt drop splashes). Using the wet towels to clean the area makes it disappear while wet, but it reappears once the wood is fully dry. Is there any trick to fixing this?

I recognize that this is somewhat peripherally about martial arts, but given how common wood floors are at the schools I've been to, and how much sweating goes on, I suspect there's some wisdom I am unaware of.

Comment: Do you not use mats?

Comment: No. Unless we're training flips, we generally don't use mats in class. Which... I realize I never said what style I was training. :-D

Comment: Maybe you should consider some light mats. They  are much easier to clean and don't really interfere with your movements. https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9828/are-eva-foam-mats-good-for-training/9829#9829

Comment: Never had to worry about this, so I'm not sure. You'll probably just need to use a hardwood floor cleaner (liquid) with a hardwood floor mop. Buy a small amount and test in a small area first to see what happens. If it's not going away with that, you might end up just having to do a full clean, buff/sand, restain, and refinish. But that should be overkill for a simple sweat stain. Sweat is more of a problem for hardwood floors if the floors don't have any finish protecting them anymore, like if it's worn away over time. Then you definitely need to do this extra work.